# How Scopus CSAB plan to evaluate a submitted journal's citedness in Scopus?

Tags: citations, journals, editors, indexing, scopus

Our journal applied to Scopus for inclusion a few months ago and I, as an editor, would like to clarify some citations to our journal from articles already indexed in this database (as far as I know, the Scopus Content Selection and Advisory Board will be looking for the citedness of our articles in Scopus and the outcome will affect the result of the journal evaluation process).

Though there are some articles in Scopus that cite articles published in our journal, many of those citations are corrupted: Our journal's name is not given in full, sometimes author/article details are missing or misrepresented etc. I contacted Scopus Author Support but they informed me that they can only process my request once our journal is indexed in Scopus. Until than, they will not modify the incorrect citations.

Now I'm wondering how Scopus CSAB plan to evaluate our journal's citedness in Scopus if their database do not show these existing references properly? I was barely able to find them in Scopus and only succeeded because I knew exactly what I was looking for. If I've simply used advanced search and searched to our journal's name within the references (what I'm expecting the committee will do) I would have found no citations to our journal whatsoever.

Is there anything more I can do in this situation?

Comment: Have you been about to find anything out from Scopus?  I see that the advisory board was expected to meet in October.

Comment: no :(  Operators on the live chat directed me to addresses from where  I only received form emails.

Answer (score 1):

For Scopus, like for any organization, if you can't find anything out online and aren't getting information back via email, then the next step is to call them on the phone and be persistent in finding the right person to talk to.

Beyond that, they are a private organization owner by Elsevier (a for-profit company), and there is no mandate that requires them to have either a transparent or a sane process, and there is likely little more advice that anyone outside of the organization can give you.